# Estimation of multivariate time-varying cross-sectional data

Tags: matlab, multivariate-regression, mixed-model

I want to estimate the following model for each variable $y_{ti}$:
$$
 y_{ti} =\alpha_t + \beta_t w_{ti} + \gamma_t u_{ti} + \delta_i x_{ti} + \phi_i z_{ti} + \varepsilon_{ti}, \quad \quad \text{for } i=1,...,k \quad t=1,...,T 
$$
I can't succeed in writing this in matrix form. Therefore, I have no idea how to estimate this model in MATLAB. My attempt at writing this model in matrix form is below, but obviously I could only include the variables of the first observed time series $y_{11},\dots,y_{T1}$.  How do I include the other variables so I can actually estimate this model?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{11}       & y_{12} & y_{13} & \dots & y_{1k} \\
    y_{21}       & y_{22} & y_{23} & \dots & y_{2k} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    y_{T1}       & y_{T2} & y_{T3} & \dots & y_{Tk}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & w_{11} & u_{11} & x_{11} & z_{11} \\
    1       & w_{21} & u_{21} & x_{21} & z_{21} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    1       & w_{T1} & u_{T1} & x_{T1} & z_{T1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha_t       & \alpha_t & \dots & \alpha_t \\
    \beta_t       & \beta_t & \dots & \beta_t \\
    \gamma_t       & \gamma_t & \dots & \gamma_t \\
    \delta_1       & \delta_2 & \dots & \delta_k \\
    \phi_1       & \phi_2 & \dots & \phi_k \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Instead of using a multivariate regression, my first intuition was to fit a linear mixed-effects model (see Matlab docs at [this link](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/linear-mixed-effects-models.html)). However, this does not cover multivariate applications.

My current solution is to use a mixed-effects model with a vectorized observation matrix. I would then include a group variable that indicates which observations come from the same cross-section. Therefore, I would basically create $T$ different groups with $T$ different cross-sections.

Is this the correct approach to my problem? Is there any other way to estimate above model?

Comment: Yes, what you do is very reasonable. Consider using a random slope (ie. ` ... + (t|id)`). I think you might benefit from checking the [repeated measures model](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel-class.html) that is also available but in general your LME is standard approach for this.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you for the confirmation. Could you explain why you propose the random slope?

Comment: It seems like you have repeated measurements per subject. Therefore the possibility of some subject-specific slope variation is there. It is not a necessity, but it would be an obvious thing to check.